# Развернуть свой сервер GIT на Windows

Tags: git, tortoise-git

возникла необходимость, пока не будет арендован сервер в большем репозитории для проекта, чем это дают популярные ресурсы по типу gitlab и т.д.

Сейчас пробую развернуть сервер через черепашкуgit. Но опыта маловато. Можете подсказать ответы на следующие вопросы.

Задача стоит в следующем, необходим большой репозиторий под разные ассеты с доступом, хотя бы по локальной сети(Radmin), но лучше через ip и порт. Чтобы можно было хранить, помимо кода - еще и ассеты(модели, UI, звуки и т.д).
Через что и как это можно сделать, желательно под windows

1. Как работает черепашка, можно ли сделать хост репозитория на своей машине с помощью нее?
2. Если делать черещз черепашку, то это просто gui для гита или же там есть возможность хостить и поднимать сервер по желанию?
3. Есть ли какие-нибудь аналоги для моей задачи? Знаю, что можно через чистый гит, но хотелось бы, хотя бы минимум интерфейса, просто команды в виде кнопок, как в том же tortoiseGIT сделано
4. Буду признателен за подробные гайды

P.S. Всем спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: берешь любой линукс по вкусу. ставишь себе на своей винде роль хайперви. https://about.gitlab.com/install/  ставишь отсюда по инструкции гитлаб, для начала хватит за глаза, если ты параноик и боишься хранить репозитории у них на бесплатном аккаунте. помоему еще у битбукета были закрытые репозитории бесплатные.

Comment: Я бы все-таки хотел под windows поставить серв, у гитлаба решения только под линукс, а у меня ряд траблов с вируалкой и линуксом

Comment: черепашка хоть и выглядит странно, это просто наивный gui. Если хочется сервер, а знаний не хватает, возьмите gogs/gitea и по [инструкции](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/windows-service/) все настройте. Там очень просто. А потом поймете, нужно оно Вам или нет.